# NSString edit via for loop - iOS

Tags: ios, for-loop, uiimageview, int

I have a simple for loop which changes the images in a set of 9 UIImageViews. However, I have one problem, I can't change the name of the UIImageView in co-ordination of the for loop and so the end result is that the for loop ONLY affects 1 out of 9 UIImageViews I have in my iOS App.

Here is my code:

```
for (current_photo = 1; current_photo < 10; current_photo++) {
        picview_1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.png", SERVER_URL, current_photo]];
    }
```

You will notice that in my code there is a bit:

```
picview_1.image
```

When I replace the "pic view_1" which "picview_current_photo", it comes up with errors.

What am I doing wrong? Please explain.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of `UIImageView`s, and access them in a loop through an index, like this:

```
NSArray *imageViews = @[picview_1, picview_2, picview_3, picview_4, ..., picview_9];
// Arrays are indexed from zero, so I changed the index to run from 0 to 9
for (current_photo = 0; current_photo < 9; current_photo++) {
    // Since current_photo is zero-based, I added one to it in stringWithFormat
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.png", SERVER_URL, current_photo+1]];
    [[imageViews objectAtIndex:current_photo] setImage:img];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Superb solution. And I'm still a beginner programmer so using an Array didn't come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best to set up an array of UIImageViews.  Then access the UIImageView that you need from that array and set the image as required.